# Sequelize Insert Cascade

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

im trying insert in multiple tables.

let me explain User create a new client, client insert id into bill - (idClient) table

this is the payload

```
{
  "name": "Evelyn",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phone": "4534534",
  "email": "eve@hotmail.com",
  "identification": "xxxxx",
  "services": [1, 2, 3],
  "bill":{
    "description": "New project"
  }
}
```

the insert

```
_service.create = async (client) => {
 const { description } = client.bill;
 try {
   const data = await Client.create(
    { client, bill: { description: description } },
    { include: { model: Bill } }
   );
  return data.id;
} catch (err) {
    handleError = err.hasOwnProperty("errors")
      ? err.errors.map((error) => error.message)
      : err;
    throw new Error(handleError);
  }
};
```

but im getting this error

```
{
 "name": "Error",
 "message": "ReferenceError: description is not defined"
}
```

and yes, bill table has that column.

the relation

```
Client.hasOne(models.Bill, { foreignKey: "idClient" });
```

so, im stuck, i read the documentation and i trying to do the same way as they do but i dont know what i doing wrong

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html

Comment: I don't see where did you get `description` variable.

Comment: yeah ma bad, i miss that

Answer (score 0):

I already did, i dont know if the best way

i modified the payload

```
{
  "name": "Evelyn",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phone": "4534534",
  "email": "eve@hotmail.com",
  "identification": "xxxxx",
  "description": "new Proyect",
}
```

the insert query, change bill to Bill as my table name and then add description value

```
const { description } = client;
const data = await Client.create(
  { ...client, Bill: { description } },
  { include: { model: Bill } }
);
```

and the result

```
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Evelyn",
"lastName": "Doe",
"phone": "4534534",
"email": "eve@hotmail.com",
"identification": "xxxxx",
"idStatus": 2,
"createdAt": "2020-11-13T08:52:37.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2020-11-13T08:52:37.000Z",
"Bill": {
  "id": 4,
  "idClient": 6,
  "totalAmount": null,
  "description": "new Proyect",
  "idStatus": 2,
  "createdAt": "2020-11-13T08:52:37.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-11-13T08:52:37.000Z"
  }
}
```